# How to multi-bind protocol implementations in Swift?

Tags: swift, dependency-injection

Say I have a hypothetical marketplace for cats. These cats are provided by a number of cat distributors, including the SPCA, Cats-R-Us, and the pound. I would like to provide a common interface through which CatProvider's may display their cats. I would also like to allow the implementors of the CatProvider protocol to be able to register to provide cats, with my application having no specific knowledge of their existence. For example:

```
protocol Cat {
  let name: String { get }
  let price: Float { get }
}

protocol CatProvider {
  func getCats() -> [Cat]
}

class CatService {
  func allCats() -> Set<Cat> {
    let catProviders: [CatProvider] = // Get all of the cat providers.
    return catProviders.reduce(Set<Cat>()) {
      cats, provider in
      return cats.union(Set(provider.getCats()))
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to determine the best way to allow my CatProvider's to multi-bind themselves to the CatProvider protocol without CatService's knowledge. I.e. I do not want CatService to ever instantiate a CatProvider. Is it possible to do this in Swift? In Objective-C I would have a binding macro at the top of each of their files, but I'm not sure how to achieve the same result here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by adding an `NSHashTable` to keep a weak reference to any provider that registers itself.

```
class CatService {
    private let providers = NSHashTable.weakObjectsHashTable()

    // stuff
}
```

Now, let's provide a means for adding (and if you wish, removing) providers:

```
class CatService {
    private let providers = NSHashTable.weakObjectsHashTable()

    func addProvider(provider: CatProvider) {
        providers.addObject(provider)
    }

    // optional:
    func removeProvider(provider: CatProvider) {
        providers.removeObject(provider)
    }
}
```

We can return an array of all the providers, or a set.

As an array:

```
var allProviders: [CatProvider]? {
    return providers.allObjects as? [CatProvider]
}
```

As a set:

```
var allProviders: Set<CatProvider>? {
    return providers.setRepresentation as? Set<CatProvider>
}
```

And of course, we can use either `providers.allObjects` or `providers.setRepresentation` to fast-enumerate the providers for whatever we're actually using this `CatService` class for, if needed.

Comment: And hopefully, in the near future, `NSHashTable` will be able to be used as `NSHashTable<CatProvider>`, which improves either `allProviders` getter.

Comment: Hi @nhgrif, thanks for your reply. The main part of the question I was looking for is how to get the cat providers to add themselves with the addProvider method. In objective-c I would have a macro at the top of the file to get the shared instance of the cat service and call addProvider on it, but I am not sure how to write code that is automatically executed in Swift.